# Pandas dataframe, merge by intersection of spans?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes based on overlap of spans (indicated by pairs (s,e), s- start of span, e - end of span), and while I have a pretty bad code for doing it, I would like to know if there is a good way to implement it. Here is example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'s':[0,10,20,33,424,5345],
                'e':[3,17,30,39,1000,10987],
                'data1':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'s':[1,45,0],
                    'e':[50,46,90],
                    'data2':[1,2,3]})

def overlap(a1,a2,b1,b2):
    if type(b1) == list or type(b1)==np.ndarray:
        assert(len(b1)==len(b2))
        return np.asarray([overlap(a1,a2,b1[k],b2[k]) for k in range(len(b1))])
    else:
        return max((a2-a1)+(b2-b1)+min(a1,b1)-max(b2,a2)+1,0)

overlaps = [overlap(df1['s'].iloc[i],df1['e'].iloc[i],df2['s'].values,df2['e'].values)>0 
        for i in range(len(df1))]
df1['data2']=[df2['data2'][o].tolist() for o in overlaps]
```

Output is:

```
    s   e   data1   data2
0   0   3   1   [1, 3]
1   10  17  2   [1, 3]
2   20  30  3   [1, 3]
3   33  39  4   [1, 3]
4   424 1000    5   []
5   5345    10987   6   []
```

Edit: also, in my particular case I am guaranteed that for df1 spans are non-overlapping and sequential (ie s[i]>s[i-1], e[i]>s[i], e[i] < s[i+1] )

Edit2: you can generate arbitrary amount of almost valid fake data (here we don't have guarantees on non-overlapping of spans in first df):

```
N=int(1e3)
sdf1=np.random.randint(0, high=10*N, size=(N,))
sdf1.sort()
edf1=sdf1+np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=(N,))
data1=range(N)

sdf2=np.random.randint(0, high=10*N, size=(N,))
edf2=sdf2+np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=(N,))
data2=range(N)


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'s':sdf1,
                    'e':edf1,
                    'data1':data1})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'s':sdf2,
                    'e':edf2,
                    'data2':data2})
```

Comment: What is `[1,3]` in your output ?

Comment: That is the data2 values from df2 that have overlapping span. Span (1,50), which corresponds to data2=1, and (0,90), which corresponds to data2=3, overlap the first 4 spans in df1 [(0,3) (10,17) (20,30) (33,39)].

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to pandas dataframe, you should always avoid `for` loops to process rows/columns and use `apply`, `transform` or other pandas functions. For example to get the overlaps you can do:

```
def has_overlap(a1, a2, b1, b2):
    ''' return True if spans overlap, otherwise return False '''
    return (a2-a1)+(b2-b1)+min(a1,b1)-max(b2,a2)+1 > 0

def find_overlap(row1):
    '''return indices of df2 which overlap with the given row of df1 as a list'''
    df2['has_overlap'] = df2.apply(lambda row2: has_overlap(row1.s, row1.e, row2.s, row2.e), axis=1)
    return list(df2['data2'].loc[df2['has_overlap']])

df1['data2'] = df1.apply(lambda row: find_overlap(row), axis=1)
print('df1: {}'.format(df1))
```

Comment: Hi, this solution seems significantly slower than even my code. Testing with 1000 records my solution is 9.02s, the solution you proposed is 90.4s, about 10x slower. I edited my post with how to generate arbitrary amount of fake data.

Comment: Apparently your original `overlap` recursive function is faster than a second row-wise apply on df2.